# Install Canon's EOS app for windows software in Debian 10 using playonlinux

Tags: debian, wine, iso

I'm using Debian 10 with Gnome.

I have an ISO file for Windows apps from Canon, including their EOS utility and Digital Photo Professional.

I would like to install that into my Debian 10.

Using playonlinux, it crashes before the installation begin.

What is the correct mode to installing it?

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to install Microsoft's Windows, or that you are trying to install software  that is designed to run on Microsoft's Windows?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly good question. Please don't down vote or close, because you knew better. You knowing better is the whole reason that we ask questions. However the question does need clarity, so please add a comment requesting this. Be as specific as you can. (Close vote requesting clarity, needs clarity. I.e why does it need clarity?) (Close vote saying it is off topic, is wrong, because it is only off topic when you know the answer. However clarity may clear this up.) When we know what is wanted, we can tell the OP how to do what they are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to install a software that originally run on microsoft windows. It's the canon package, that include eos utility and digital photo professional (and others software). I have an iso file of that software

Comment: How does it crash before it starts? Do you mean before it goes much / at the start? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: it crash before the installation begin, when I select the ISO file and press ok to start the installation. I try to extract the .exe from the iso file, but nothing change

Comment: "when I select the ISO file and press ok to start the installation" -- so just after the start. Can you tell us more about what you did, and what happened?

Answer (score 3):

[Playonlinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-2-0.html)  has no information on how to use it with the Canon EOS app nor the Digital Photo Professional app. WineHQ tried it several times and [each time it failed](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8626). You may wish to also check at https://www.playonlinux.com/en/forums.html for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install Microsoft's Windows Operating System, then Play on Linux / Wine is not the way to go. These are for running software that is designed to run on Microsoft's Windows OS, on Gnu/Linux.

To run Microsoft's Windows OS within Debian Gnu/Linux. First install Virtual Box. Then within that create a virtual machine, configure as MS-Windows (name it windows 7 or as appropriate, and it will do the configuration for you), attach the ISO CD/DVD image, allocate some diskspace, and press run. Then follow the install procedure to install the OS. Done.

You will now have Microsoft's Windows in a box. You can run it in a virtual desktop, or a window, or (if you install the guest add-ons into MS-Windows) in seamless mode (that is MS-Windows and X11/Gnu/Linux windows together).

Comment: "I have an ISO file for Windows **apps from Canon**"